# Developing SDK 3.1.2 compatible audio.caf Files

Tags: avaudioplayer, caf

Apparently SDK 3.1.2 has a built in discrimination about certain audio.caf files being passed to AVAudioplayer.

Some files that worked fine with SDK 3.0.1 get a returned content null from AVAudioplayer using exact same code on simulator or iphone with SDK 3.1.2.

All files are 16-bit Integer, Big Endian, Mono, 22.050 KHz, Data rate 352.8 Kbits/s.
All files have same rwx permissions and ownerships and have similiar size and duration ~7 secs.

How do I get visibility to what is different about files that work and ones that don't and convert or fix the ones that don't work?

I tried running "afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@22050 input.caf output.caf" to try and get SDK 3.1.2 to accept file with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that 3.1.2 requires 11025hz in caf lpcm to work correctly. 
`afconvert -d "BEI16@11025" test2.caf test2_cool.caf` solved my issues.